# Selected check box in the list view item template is not storing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to store the selected rows using `asp:checkbox` to the `CourseParticipants` table but it doesn't store the selected records to the database. There is no error shown but it refresh to the same page and shows the checked records. I'm trying to select users.
Thank you in advance!

**Here is the markup:**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead style="background-color: #92d36e">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Employee Name</b></td>
            <td><b>Position</b></td>
            <td><b>Actions</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <asp:ListView ID="lvEmployees" runat="server" OnPagePropertiesChanging="lvEmployees_PagePropertiesChanging" OnDataBound="lvEmployees_DataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><%# Eval("FirstName")%>,<%# Eval("LastName")%></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("Position")%></td>
                    <td><asp:CheckBox ID="cbEmployee" runat="server" />
                                        </a></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </tbody>
</table>
<asp:Button ID="btnAddParticipants" runat="server"
            class="btn btn-success" OnClick="btnAddParticipants_Click"
            Text="Add Participants" />
```

**Here is the C#**

```
void GetEmployees()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon()))
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = @"SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, Position FROM Employees";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "EmployeeID");
            lvEmployees.DataSource = ds;
            lvEmployees.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}

protected void btnAddParticipants_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewDataItem item in this.lvEmployees.Items)
    {
        string idValue = lvEmployees.DataKeys[item.DataItemIndex].Value.ToString();
        if (item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("cbEmployee");
            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon()))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    string query = @"INSERT INTO CourseParticipants VALUES (@TrainingModuleID, @EmployeeID, @Active, @DateAdded)";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrainingModuleID", txtCourseID.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", idValue);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", 1);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAdded", DateTime.Now);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with `DateTime.Now`. Try using `DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: `con.Close();` is not neccesary since your connection is inside a `using` instruction

Answer (score 0):

If it's always `DateTime.Now` what you want to insert, you could use the `getdate()` function:

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO CourseParticipants VALUES (@TrainingModuleID, @EmployeeID, @Active, getdate())";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrainingModuleID", txtCourseID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", idValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", 1);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

But it's a bit DB specific, so what DB are you using? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

I would also cast/convert `txtCourseID.Text` to an int (32 or 64) depending on your db scheme. Just to make sure that it's an OK value... and not string (nvarchar).
I also removed the closing of the connection, since it's in a using block.